# Contents of Plist file getting deleted

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I am trying to save name and num in a plist stored in bundle, it is getting saved properly but the problem is that once I execute again my application, I am unable to retrive previous data stored in plist.

Here is my code for plist named sample.plist, two texfields name, number:

```
-(void)viewdidload
{
    [super viewdidload];
    self.path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"plist"];
    self.dictionary=[[NSMutabledictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:self.path];
}

-(IBAction)save
{
    if(self.dictionary==nil) {
        self.dictionary=[[NSMutabledictionary alloc] 
        initWithObjectsAndKeys:self.name.text,self.number.text,nil];
    } else {
        self.dictionary=[NSMutabledictionary  dictionaryWithContentsofFile:self.path];
        [self.dictionary setobject:self.name.text forKey:self.number.text];
    }

    [self.dictionary writetofile:self.path];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find many question related to this issue in SO. It is a very simple issue your plist is in application bundle which is a read-only information.

If you want to edit the contents move the plist to documents directory when you access the plist for the first time. Consequently always use that path for all read/write operations.

Whenever you need the path of plist use the following method

```
- (NSString *)savedPlistPath{

NSString *documents = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                          NSUserDomainMask,
                                                          YES)[0];

NSString *filePath = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.plist"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {

    NSString *bundleFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"plist"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundleFilePath toPath:filePath error:nil];

}
return filePath;
```

}

Comment: @user2440960 Glad to help you. Do accept the answer if it's helpful. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and perhaps this solution could help. Rather than creating the plist file in xcode and pushing it to the device, write a new file in the document directory.

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
self.filePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.plist"];
[self.dictionary writeToFile:self.filePath atomically:YES];
```

As @Anupdas points out, the plist in the bundle is read-only.